# How do I remove string from tkinter Listbox and from the list that was inserted?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, listbox

I have a list of strings inserted into a Tkinter `Listbox` and I need to click a button to remove a user selection (`curselection`) from both the `Listbox` and the list that was inserted.

```
# list
fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape']

#listbox, insert list in Listbox
list_of_fruit = Listbox(root, height = 7, width = 25, bg = 'white',
                        activestyle = 'dotbox')
list_of_fruit.grid(column = 3, row = 1, sticky = W)
for c in fruit:
    list_of_fruit.insert(END, c)

#delete button
delete_fruit_button = ttk.Button(root, text = 'DELETE', width = 15,
                                 command = lambda: delete()).grid(column = 2, row = 1,
                                                                  sticky = W)

#function to delete from Listbox and list
def delete():
    #delete from Listbox
    selection = list_of_fruit.curselection()
    list_of_fruit.delete(selection)
    #delete from list
    value = eval(list_of_fruit.get(selection))
    fruit.remove(value)
```

When I click the button on the GUI the selected string is removed from the `Listbox`, but not the list that populates it. I receive 1 of 2 errors as well whenever I click the button to remove, for example, `'apple'`:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?
```

or

```
NameError: name 'orange' is not defined
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `eval()`. Just use `value = list_of_fruit.get(selection)` the `fruit.remove(value)` to remove it from the list. The `get()` method of a `StringVar` returns a string. Note you might want to check the value and make sure it's not the empty string before trying to remove it.

Comment: You're deleting items from the listbox and then trying to get those same items from the listbox. Have you considered getting the items before you delete them?

Comment: Thanks for reformatting my question and providing answers, it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a couple of items before I could execute your code.  You did a good job of providing a minimal example, but it should be executable code.  I added your imports, root = Tk and root.mainloop to run it.  The list_of_fruit.curselection() returns a tuple with one member.
you need to index the selection to get the number to use to remove the item from the list.
Here is your updated delete function:

```
'    #function to delete from Listbox and list
def delete():
    #delete from Listbox
    selection = list_of_fruit.curselection()
    list_of_fruit.delete(selection)
    fruit.pop(selection[0])  # selection is a tuple with one member
    #delete from list
    #value = eval(list_of_fruit.get(selection))
    #fruit.remove(value)'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Jim, got it to work now.